# Change number fo share from a Whatsapp quiz Code

Tags: javascript, html, css, xcode, typescript

Please this is script for free WhatsApp quiz traffic

Normally I share QUIZ 15 times on Whatsapp and It gives me the result But I want to replace it Through this code

I want to show the result after only 5 share

Thanks

```
  function incrementValue()
  {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    shared(value);
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;

    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    if(value>= STRONG.share){
      window.location="/result.html";
    }else{
        //alert("Você compartilhou com "+value+" Amigos. São no mínimo 15 compartilhamentos!");
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the value in STRONG.share

```
if(value>= STRONG.share){
```

you could do

```
STRONG.share = 10;
```

or change the if statement itself

```
if(value>= 10){
```